# How to properly calculate ETH balance of the wallet from native transactions

Tags: transactions, ether, etherscan

Can someone please help me to understand how ETH balance to be calculated for this address:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6B300C1Aa4a9a91758f20C57861Ed8AB2b2540F6

In my understanding this wallet has sent more ETH than it has. What i'm missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check internal transactions, you can see that actually, this address had enough Ethers to send before transactions, as it swapped some amount of [ALBT](https://etherscan.io/token/0x00a8b738e453ffd858a7edf03bccfe20412f0eb0) for Ether using 1Inch:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6B300C1Aa4a9a91758f20C57861Ed8AB2b2540F6#internaltx

[Here](https://info.etherscan.com/understanding-an-ethereum-transaction/) you can see a description of what internal transaction actually means.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Bogdan. Does that mean that amount of swap to ETH made part of the internal transaction has to be added address ETH balance.
Are internal transactions the only way to link ERC20 tokens to ETH?

Comment: As converting ERC20 tokens to ETH and vice versa require interaction with a smart contract of some kind (Exchanges), then I do believe this will always be the case. So yes, those kinds of interactions and swaps will always be listed as internal transactions.